# How to purge the Gmail trash from a time driven trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

How can I purge my Gmail trash, using a script triggered to run at a specific time interval?

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you checked the documentation on the Gmail API or Google App Scripts?   Yes it is possible.

Comment: Kindly add more details to the question. The body isn't describing the question title.

Comment: DalmTo, thx for an useful for an useful answer -> "Yes it is possible".        It encourage me to dig through more of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  
// A google app script for purgeing my gmail trash.
// 
// It did work but is there a better way to do this ?
//
function delete_my_gmail_trash() {
    var threads = GmailApp.search( "in:trash" );


    for ( var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++ ) {
        num_of_messages_in_the_thread = threads[i].getMessageCount();
        for ( var j = 0; j < num_of_messages_in_the_thread; j++ ) {
          Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete( {  "ids": [threads[i].getMessages()[j].getId() ]}, "me" );

        }
      }
}
```